# How to get xpath of only the categories for checkboxes

Tags: xpath

I am trying to find the xpath / count for all the checkboxes under "Categories".
but when I am trying to get xpath/count it is getting me all the checkboxes under "Categories" and under "Brands"

How can I get all checkboxes count under "Categories".

attaching the screenshot for the issue, Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi please show the DOM for both category and  brand,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the element structure for the brand also. Assuming, all elements under Brand and categories are under different levels, the xpath you could use is:

```
//h5[text()='Categories']/../../digital-coupons-filter-by-types/div
```

**It seems both are in the same level:**

i tested below locator:

```
//li[preceding-sibling::*//div[text()='SHOP BY CATEGORY']/..][following-sibling::*//a[@data-menu-id="10"]/..]
```

and also:

```
//li[following-sibling::*//a[@data-menu-id="11"]/..]
```

For amazon uk:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/:  click the handburger menu and try out your self

[image]

**so in your case you could use:**

```
//div[following-sibling::*//h5[text()='Brands']/..]
```

Comment: Thank you, but its counting all the checkboxes under "category" and "brands", I have attached updated screenshot of how the elements are defined under the category.

Comment: @Ravi see the updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution worked. :)

Comment: @Ravi please also accept the answer by clicking the tick sign

Comment: can you let me know where is the tick sign ? I don't see it on my page.

Comment: @Ravi https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106324/359323 please refer this , there will be a tick sign near to my answer . Just click it

Comment: Done, Thank you so much.